# NodeJS: Need idiomatic: Read files in dir, concatenate, transform, write

Tags: node.js, shell, io, promise

I'm trying to write a content manglement program in Node. I'm an old Ruby / Perl / Shell hand for many years, and I can't seem to get simple code that works in those languages to look similarly, eh, simple, in Node.

**Task**: Find all the `*.md` files, read them (in `ls` order), transform them, and bracket them with a header comment and a footer comment. The files, in order, have a pieces of Markdown that, when assembled and transformed, are a sensible HTML doc. Here's a shell implementation:

`echo '<!-- Generate at:' $(date) ' -->' $(ls *.md |xargs cat|markdown)'<!-- Copyright Mumble-demo Inc. -->'`

Produces the desired HTML:

```
<!-- Generate at: Tue Jun 6 08:25:59 EDT 2017  --> <h1>This is a Markdown File</h1> <h2>Heading 1</h2> <p>Inside of markdown we can create many interesting items</p> <ul> <li>such</li> <li>as</li> <li>lists</li> </ul><!-- Copyright Mumble-demo Inc. -->
```

Ruby is similarly reasonable...

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'kramdown'

HEADER = "<!-- Generated at #{Time.now} -->\n"
FOOTER = "\n<!-- Copyright Mumble-demo Inc. -->"

OUTPUT = File.open("./output", "w")

results =  Dir.glob("*.md").map { |f| File.open(f).readlines.join() }.reduce(:+)
OUTPUT.print(HEADER, Kramdown::Document.new(results).to_html, FOOTER)
```

But I can't figure out how to do this in Node in a Way That Feels Right(™)

A Way That Feels Wrong(™) is with the synchronous interfaces:

```
const fs = require("fs")
const marked = require("marked")

const HEADER = `<!-- Generated at ${new Date()} -->\n`
const FOOTER = `\n<!-- Copyright Mumble-demo Inc. -->`

fs.readdir(".", (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  let markdownFiles = files.filter((f) => f.endsWith(".md"))

  let content = markdownFiles.reduce((memo, fileName) => {
    return memo + fs.readFileSync(fileName, 'utf8')
  }, "")

  let contentString = [HEADER, marked(content), FOOTER].reduce((m, i) => m + i, "")
  fs.writeFileSync("derp", contentString);
  console.log(contentString);

})
```

A Way That Feels Right But That I Can't Get To Work(™) is:

1. Build read streams
2. Pipe them to markdown transform streams
3. Open an output stream and redirect transformed data to it

Great news is – this approach works until it comes time to put the header comments in at the top and the bottom. They live in the code, not on the filesystem so I can't "just add" them as another file to stream, sans transform, into the output stream. Most approaches wind up producing: header, footer, streamed data

Obviously the `pipe()`-work works asynchronously and the footer print fires before the read + transform work is done. I've tried horrible (and broken) `Promise` chains that ultimately did not work.

One alternate approach would be to turn the header and footer into streams (seems weird...) and flow them into the output stream as well (seems really weird).

I've stumped several seasoned developers with this...surely we're missing some common idiom here or is it *actually* this hard to do this simple task simply in Node?

Answer (score 1):

Thoughts:

- For most of my shell scripts, I simply read file contents into strings, synchronously. This approach doesn’t scale, but it usually doesn’t need to. And everything is so much easier with strings.
- If you do anything asynchronous: Use async functions and [`util.promisify()`](http://2ality.com/2017/05/util-promisify.html).
- Long-term, [asynchronous iteration and async generators](http://2ality.com/2016/10/asynchronous-iteration.html) will help with this kind of scenario, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it "A Way That Feels Right" via synchronous executor [nsynjs](https://github.com/amaksr/nsynjs). Your code may transform similarly to this working example:

md-cat.js:

```
var nsynjs = require('nsynjs');
var nsynFs = require('../wrappers/nodeFs'); // part of nsynjs package, needs to be added manually

var synchronousCode = function(nsynFs) {
    var HEADER = "<!-- Generated at "+new Date()+" -->\n";
    var FOOTER = "\n<!-- Copyright Mumble-demo Inc. -->";

    var files = nsynFs.readdir(nsynjsCtx, ".").data;

    var content="";
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if(file.endsWith('.md'))
            content+=nsynFs.readFile(nsynjsCtx,file,"utf8").data;
    }
    nsynFs.writeFile(nsynjsCtx,"derp",HEADER+content+FOOTER);
};

nsynjs.run(synchronousCode, {},nsynFs, function () {
    console.log('synchronousCode done')
});
```

Even though it looks synchronous, it does not use any synchronous functions under the hood, therefore it will not block node's event loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com), which is a most idiomatic way nowadays.

If can't or don't want, use Promise chains, they feels like shell pipes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const path = require('path');
const marked = require('marked');

const HEADER = `<!-- Generated at ${(new Date()).toISOString()} -->`;
const FOOTER = '<!-- Copyright Mumble-demo Inc. -->';

fs.readdirAsync(process.cwd())
  .map((fileName) => Promise.all([fileName, fs.statAsync(fileName)]))
  .filter(([fileName, stat]) => stat.isFile() && path.extname(fileName) === '.md')
  .call('sort', ([a], [b]) => a.localeCompare(b, 'en-US'))
  .map(([mdFileName]) => fs.readFileAsync(mdFileName, 'utf8'))
  .then((mdFiles) => {
    let out = [HEADER, marked(mdFiles.join('\n')), FOOTER].join('').replace(/\n/g, '');
    console.log(out);
    return fs.writeFileAsync('out.html', out);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Thoughts:

- Never write sync code in Node, you will always regret.
- Promise chains work best for such tasks.
- stat.isFile() and sort(), are just safety features, missing in bash and Ruby examples. Removing them you can save two lines of code.
- Usage of Date.prototype.toString() should be considered as a bug in most cases, because output is unpredictable, it is platform and locale specific.
- Node streams are overkill until you deal with huge files, which is usually not a case for markdown tasks.
- Shell pipes are also not using file system streams and load everything in a memory. Efficiency roughly the same.